Showing $\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{(i+n-2)!}{i!}(1-p)^{i}=\frac{(n-2)!}{p^{n-1}}$
I am given the following series $$\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{(i+n-2)!}{i!}(1-p)^{i}$$ where $|1-p|<1$ and I am asked to show that $$\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{(i+n-2)!}{i!}(1-p)^{i}=\frac{(n-2)!}{p^{n-1}}$$ So far, my attempts in proving this have not been successfull, I guess one has to use power series of the exponential somehow and derive or integrate but I don't see how because the numerator of the general term of the series depends on $i$, i.e. $a_n=\frac{(i+n-2)!}{i!}$ has a numerator which depends on $i$.

Write $(i+n-2)!/i!=(i+1)(i+2)\cdots (i+n-2)$ and replace $1-p$ with $x.$ Then you will see the sum is the $n-2$th derivative of $$\sum_{j\geq 0}^\infty x^j=\frac1{1-x}.$$

You'll have to use a separate case when $n=0,1,$ if you wantt those cases, but then you can't start at $i=0.$

It's worth substituting $m=n-2,$ because the $n-2$ is irrelevant.

Wow! That's great! If you make this comments an answer I will check mark your answer. Thanks anyways!

Probably worth closing this question - I'm sure it has been asked in some form or other many times already.

Doing what has been said as a comment.

If $$f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}x^k$$ for $|x|<1$ which has sum $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and taking the $(n-2)$-th derivative one gets $$\sum_{k\geq n-2}k(k-1)\dots(k-n+3)x^{k-(n-2)}=\frac{(n-2)!}{(1-x)^{n-1}}$$ which is exacly the series we where looking for $$\sum_{k\geq n-2}k(k-1)\dots(k-n+3)x^{k-(n-2)}=(n-2)(n-3)\dots(1)+$$ $$(n-1)(n-2)\dots(2)x+(x)(n-1)\dots(3)x^{2}+\dots$$ So my original sum is $$\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{(i+n-2)!}{i!}(1-p)^{i}=f^{(n-2)}(1-p)=\frac{(n-2)!}{p^{n-1}}$$

